# ios how to show activity indicator during fetching the data from rss feed in UITableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, rss, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to populating the data from a rss feed. This process take some time. During this delay I want to display a activity indicator and hide it when data is loaded.  how can I do it? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add a `UIActivityIndicator` subview.
2. During the start of loading make it visible. You can disable all user interaction if you want and also can apply a semitransparent view to let users know that interaction is disabled.
3. Start asynchronous loading of data. You must do asynchronous loading. In synchronous loading everything, including UI update, is blocked. So indicator won't animate in that case.
4. When data loading is completed stop the connecting animation. And enable the interaction if disabled earlier.

And that's all.